# MySQL Pivot Tables Without Numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I trying to do a pivot table from this table.
[image]

I want a table like this:

[image]

**I want my headers in a column.**

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: show us your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select 'field1' as field, field1 from t
union all
select 'field2' as field, field2 from t
union all
select 'field3' as field, field3 from t
union all
select 'field4' as field, field4 from t;
```